# Rails: undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The error I'm getting is: `undefined method >= for nil:NilClass` highlighting this line:

```
<%= content_tag :td, class: "tier#{pg.tier}" do -%>
```

I'm not sure what the issue is. It had been working in the past but now it isn't. As you could see, printing out `pg.name` works right above the line with the problem, so I don't know why it's saying that `pg` is `nil`.

**View**

```
<% @point_guards.each do |pg| %>
    <% puts pg.name # working %>
    <%= content_tag :td, class: "tier#{pg.tier}" do -%>
        <%= link_to pg.name, "/#{@team.name.downcase}/#{pg.link}" %>
    <% end -%>
<% end %>
```

**Player.rb**

```
def tier
    return 1 if overall_rank >= 1 && overall_rank <= 15
    return 2 if overall_rank >= 16 && overall_rank <= 45
    return 3 if overall_rank >= 46 && overall_rank <= 75
    return 4 if overall_rank >= 76 && overall_rank <= 105
    return 5 if overall_rank >= 106 && overall_rank <= 135
    return 6 if overall_rank >= 136 && overall_rank <= 175
end
```

**Github**: https://github.com/adamzerner/sports_site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're calling `pg.tier` on that line. `pg.tier` tries to compare `overall_rank`, but according to the error message, `overall_rank` is `nil`.

Comment: That's odd. I just checked in the console and `player.overall_rank` is returning the rank it should. Are you sure that it's saying `overall_rank` is `nil` rather than saying `pg` is `nil`?

Comment: Oh woops you're right, there are players for which `overall_rank` is `nil`. One sec...

Comment: So I added `return 7 if overall_rank == nil` to `Player.rb`. Why isn't that fixing the issue?

Comment: Did you add that as the first line of `tier`?

Comment: So you're still trying to compare `overall_rank` 12 times before you check if it's `nil`?

Comment: Ah I get it, thanks! Adding it to the first line worked.